# Using POST node in KNIME

Tags: javascript, knime

When trying to get Auth token I get a 401 error.

```json
{
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "error",
    "type" : "InvalidRequestException",
    "text" : "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter.",
    "fields" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

I would love some help on connecting to an API to retrieve a Token.

I have triple-checked the URL and the credentials.
I feel there is another step or setting I need to add.

From the website of the API here is the example:

```
var settings = {
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "(add URL)",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "partner_id": "partner12345",
    "client_id": "id12345",
    "client_secret": "secret12345",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "(list of access)"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I have tested this in Postman and it works with all the same information that I am testing in KNIME analytics.
I have not been able to get the token to generate in KNIME POST request node I get the error above.

If you have any ideas or insights please let me know.

I expect a JSON formatted token to return that I can use as Auth for the GET request to the API.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also please provide more information about what you are trying to do. E.g.: What API do you want to use?

Comment: Thank for that feedback, @IkonoDim I am using EzyVet API to collect data to put in a table. KNIME makes it really easy to convert the JSON data to a table and perform  some ETL. In order to call the API I need the Token first then a regular GET request.

I have all credentials and have it working in Postman but trying to get this working in KNIME to build a workflow around it.

Comment: Is there any way you can see how the request that knime is doing looks like? E.g. set up a middleman server real quick and listen to what is happening.

Comment: I know it's hard to explain thank you for responding. 
I did figure out how to get it working. 

I know it needs to be in a JSON format and originally I input it like this. 
Turns out I need it all on one line (terrible for readability) but if I have spaces at all it won't read it.

Comment: ```partner_id=partner12345&
    client_id=id12345&
    client_secret=secret12345&
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    scope=list of access.```

Comment: can't figure out to display but I wrote it so they were each on a separate line for readability originally.

Comment: Sooo.. It works now?